# Cannot view full width of very long table

Tags: microsoft-word

I inherited a very long table (600 pages) Word 10.   I use Word 16.  The width is wider than my screen.  The file only shows the right half of the table in all views except "Outline"      When switched to outline view, I can move it horizontally to see the whole table.  In any other view, the left half of table is missing.
Any fix?

Answer (score 0):

Change the paper size to Ledger (11x17) and the orientation to Landscape. Hopefully, that will let you get at the columns to adjust them as you need.

You can also set the maximum table width from Table Properties > Table > Size > Preferred Width. Just be aware that shrinking a really wide table will cause the length to grow in response. So this is only a stop gap until you work out a way to adjust the columns to make the table width more manageable.